# FCM onMessageReceived() never called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I know there is 2 kind of payload, notification and data. Currently, I am using data payload as I want to create custom notification and register FirebaseMessagingService in Manifest.

My expected behavior is that whenever I send push onMessageReceived() method should be called whether app is in the foreground, background or killed.

The issue currently I am facing that onMessageReceived() does not invoke for some devices when I killed app but not with all devices.

The issue is with OnePlus 5 and Lenevo.

I have also checked others app in my phone which uses Firebase for push and their custom push notification comes when app is killed.

**1. Is this issue with Firebase?**

**2. Is there any solution?**

Comment: if the app is killed not all phones will receive the notification even if u used data payload

Comment: You are right sir, but there are so many app in my phone which using Firebase for push and their push comes when app is killed. It means there is some solution

Comment: send the notification part with data

Comment: @Debdeep yes, I am using data payload only

Comment: @FaisalShaikh I think you should use notification and data payload

Comment: @Ali with notification payload, system will handle notification but I want that onMessageReceived() method should invoke as I need to show custom notification like other apps.

Comment: onMessageReceived() will not be called when your app is killed , checkout the this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: @Ali even with data payload? and if yes then how can I show a custom notification when the app is killed?

Comment: @Ali in your provided doc it's written in summary table that with only data payload onMessageReceived() will called in both foregrund & background case. It means it should called onMessageReceived() in my case.